# Put class output into DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, class

I am trying to put:

```
(60058848240, [(1593673073, 225, [(47167332646, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593672580, 224, [(47168591582, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593672469, 226, [(47172960078, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593672347, 224, [(47173599570, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593672225, 320, [(47236024748, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593672105, 287, [(47312814396, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593671864, 354, [(47373407183, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593671613, 226, [(47733417579, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593671250, 223, [(47744914371, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593671009, 258, [(47768078291, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670767, 226, [(47771086467, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670648, 223, [(47771526411, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670525, 223, [(47771606355, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670395, 226, [(47791746299, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670276, 225, [(47796612043, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670154, 224, [(47867550179, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593670034, 225, [(47870695515, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593669913, 223, [(47933193651, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593669792, 257, [(47959468867, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593669692, 226, [(47964746103, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593669311, 224, [(48025881704, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593667876, 257, [(2357595824, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593668487, 225, [(48041058548, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593668369, 224, [(48050000000, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593667635, 225, [(2394494009, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593667403, 224, [(2394930789, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593666668, 225, [(2419299523, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593666427, 224, [(2419415251, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593666306, 256, [(2462865575, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593666064, 224, [(2467804615, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593666129, 665, [(38000000000, '37yJxtQP7eeZnhEDVWXkosQhk6FiQYSsar'), (10103027149, '37yJxtQP7eeZnhEDVWXkosQhk6FiQYSsar')]), (1593665966, 224, [(2468096244, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593665483, 226, [(2470587236, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593665361, 225, [(2747586277, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593665119, 258, [(2762640068, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593663298, 225, [(2765080012, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593662815, 223, [(2765517696, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593662574, 225, [(2770385380, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593662453, 226, [(2772050456, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593662212, 258, [(2781902256, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593661973, 259, [(2794980069, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593661610, 224, [(2797151849, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593661239, 225, [(2799839036, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593661148, 224, [(2847088629, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593661016, 224, [(2850751065, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593660774, 223, [(2853703503, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593660655, 226, [(2856802871, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593660535, 258, [(2978196532, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593660413, 225, [(3057740103, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')]), (1593658723, 226, [(3157605768, '1Ptv5qNTg6bpoMrH8zKqpiSA62jC3i76Nr')])])
```

Into a DataFrame. This is the output from a function which return the output from a class. I tried:

```
frame = pd.read_json(output)
```

But i got the following error:

```
 frame = pd.read_json(output)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 569, in read_json
    path_or_buf, encoding=encoding, compression=compression
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 222, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'explorer.Address'>
```

EDIT:

For the following code:

```
frame = pd.read_json(json.dumps(output))
```

I have the following error:

```
  File "test_explo.py", line 9, in <module>
    frame = pd.read_json(json.dumps(output))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Address is not JSON serializable
```

EDIT 2:

I have changed the shape so that is should be JSON serializable as follow. I also tested t with the following link JSONLint.com.
But it is still not working..

```
{"transaction": [[1593700974, 225], [1593700792, 226], [1593700643, 224], [1593700521, 223], [1593700188, 225], [1593700128, 225], [1593700006, 225], [1593699937, 323], [1593699855, 387], [1593699795, 546], [1593699734, 226], [1593699672, 351], [1593699521, 226], [1593699180, 224], [1593698457, 257], [1593698215, 256], [1593697822, 225], [1593697762, 257], [1593697430, 226], [1593696633, 223], [1593696030, 288], [1593695968, 225], [1593695908, 294], [1593695697, 257], [1593695515, 225], [1593695364, 225], [1593695302, 223], [1593694913, 223], [1593694459, 223], [1593694186, 258], [1593693858, 223], [1593693664, 225], [1593693247, 224], [1593693002, 223], [1593692791, 223], [1593692067, 223], [1593691674, 223], [1593691554, 225], [1593690881, 225], [1593690759, 255], [1593690277, 223], [1593689883, 226], [1593689701, 226], [1593689640, 225], [1593689097, 224], [1593688967, 226], [1593688576, 224], [1593688515, 259], [1593688454, 224], [1593688302, 226]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn your output into proper JSON. You can use the `json` library for that:

```
import json

df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(output))
```

But it is unclear to me what format your output data is in, so the resulting pandas DataFrame might not be what you expect it to be and you might have to reformat your output accordingly.

Comment: I have edited with the error from your suggestion. I return a string from the class

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the output of your class properly. It is not in proper JSON renderable format.
You can verify this by copying the entire output and either check it on online tools such as [JSONLint.com](https://JSONLint.com) or simply go to chrome browser and open developer tools and in console type: `` JSON.parse(`Your string here`) ``. If they evaluate correctly without errors, that means the format is convertible to a JSON Object.

I tried to parse the output that you posted here, it is invalid JSON. So after rectifying that, follow @Alex's answer to load the JSON formatted output in a pandas data frame.

You can edit your question and post your code that gives the output if you need some help with modifying/fixing that code.

Comment: I followed your advice. Please look at my edit and comment.

Comment: @delalma your output format is still incorrect. I'd suggest having a read at https://JSON.org. You output format should be like: ```{"transaction": ["[1593700974, 225]", "[1593700792, 226]"]}```